Error NG0908 after upgrading Angular 17 SSR project to Vite/esbuild
I upgraded an Angular 17.3.6 project w/ SSR to use Vite/esbuild via:
ng update @angular/cli --name use-application-builder

After a couple of updates to fix relative path issues for server.ts, etc., the ng build command began failing with:
An unhandled exception occurred: NG0908: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
Using the --verbose argument shows that the Vite build process has completed scripts.js, pollyfills.server.mjs, polyfills.js, and server.mjs (among others) when it crashes. This is the trace in the error log file:
[error] Error: NG0908: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
    at _NgZone (C:\Source\Repos\x\x\.angular\prerender-root\bc51c716-927a-482e-8326-e43767329597\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:14668:19)
    at getNgZone (C:\Source\Repos\x\x\.angular\prerender-root\bc51c716-927a-482e-8326-e43767329597\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:14978:16)
    at _PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (C:\Source\Repos\x\x\.angular\prerender-root\bc51c716-927a-482e-8326-e43767329597\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:32235:24)
    at <anonymous> (C:\Source\Repos\x\x\.angular\prerender-root\bc51c716-927a-482e-8326-e43767329597\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:32296:41)

The only mentions of this error that I see involve zone.js not being included in a polyfills file, out-of-order loading of polyfill.js & main.js files, etc.
One other clue is that the build process does complete if the prerender option is set to false, but the goal is to use Vite's SSR, so we need it to be true.
